# How do you write a set quickly this way?

Tags: python, set

It says basically `B = [y | sqrt(y) in X]`, but when I write it in Python I get an error. I tried:

```
b_set = set([y for y**0.5 in x_set])
b_set = set([y for math.sqrt(y) in x_set])
```

Neither works.

Comment: ...where does "it" say that?

Comment: And what error do you get? Did you mean `set([y**0.5 for y in x_set])`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: You probably want the answer below, but there appears to be a mismatch with what you've tried and what you say you want. `{y | sqrt(y) in X}` would actually be read as  "the set of numbers whose square-root is in `X`". So you might want `{a**2 for a in X}`.

Comment: Thanks friends. This is a part of my task where I need to find a set X that that fulfill all of the given requirements. And this was one of them.                 B = {y | √y ∈ X}

Comment: What should the elements of the resulting `b_set` be? In Python `|` means either the bit-wise OR operator or the union operator for set objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comprehension syntax should look like `expression for identifier in collection`. You seem to have swapped the positions of `expression` and `identifier`.

```
import math
x_set = [1,4,9,16]
b = {math.sqrt(y) for y in x_set}
print b
```

Result:

```
set([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

Comment: And of course, `set(math.sqrt(y) for y in x_set)` would work too ... (just in case OP is stuck in ancient "python2.6" land)